# SQL - two months from todays date in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column that stores the last modified date. I want to check in a SQL query if its value is more than 2 months from the current date.

I know I need to use SYSDATE but am not familiar with date stuff in Oracle so am unsure as to the rest.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
 SELECT * from table where date_column >= add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1, 2);
```

Comment: I'd make it `>= add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1, 2)`. This type of condition usually assumes the date only, not datetime.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a query that will give the last 2 month data based on the current date.

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE created_on >= add_months(sysdate, -2);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT field1,field2 from yourtable where field_date > add_months(SYSDATE, 2);
```

Bye

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query WHERE clause that will get you the previous 13 months based on the current date.  For example, if today's date is 3/11/2011, the query would return 2/1/2011 through EOD 2/28/2011.

```
SELECT * FROM [my-table] WHERE [date-field] BETWEEN TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -13), 'MM') AND TRUNC (LAST_DAY (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -1))+1)
```