# Is there a command to use in SQL to extract data based on a date within the data?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm am trying to set up an auto report that will generate bi-weekly, therefore, I don't want all the date included in the prior extract to be included in the next extract.

```
SELECT request_id, request_date
FROM request_table_1
WHERE ???
```

***Unfiltered data:***

```
Request ID  Request Date
1       12/19/2019 10:21:31 PM
2       12/23/2019 10:22:26 PM
3       12/26/2019 10:21:58 PM
4       12/30/2019 10:23:20 PM
5       1/2/2020 10:21:11 PM
6       1/6/2020 10:23:27 PM
7       1/9/2020 10:21:13 PM
8       1/16/2020 10:22:07 PM
9       1/20/2020 10:22:25 PM
10      1/23/2020 10:21:30 PM
11      1/27/2020 10:20:56 PM
12      1/30/2020 10:25:55 PM
13      2/3/2020 10:25:18 PM
14      2/6/2020 10:21:57 PM
15      2/10/2020 10:21:43 PM
16      2/13/2020 10:32:11 PM
```

What can I put under ***WHERE*** so that the report only extracts the requests that were generated withing the past 14 days from the ***current date***?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL - two months from todays date in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266717/sql-two-months-from-todays-date-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
where date_column >= trunc(sysdate) - 14
```

Answer (score -2):

`WHERE request_date BETWEEN DATEADD(WEEK, -2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: Can you please explain your code?